# Automating Copyrighted Music Silencing in YouTube Videos Using the YouTube API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, live-streaming, audio-processing

I currently manually mute copyrighted songs in my YouTube videos by navigating to the video, clicking on “Restrictions,” and then muting the specific copyrighted track. However, I’d like to achieve this automatically using the YouTube API.

I run a YouTube channel where I live-stream events, and during breaks, the event organizers play music. The video captures and broadcasts this music. Given that my channel is growing, manually handling these copyright claims is becoming cumbersome.

Is it possible to automate this process using a YouTube API? If so, which API should I use, and are there any restrictions associated with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The YouTube api is very limited and does not have the power to edit copyright information.